# Как переустановить Linux ?

Tags: linux

Ситуация такая:

Есть ноут, на котором стоит линукс минт, а нужно установить centOS. Играть с дисками/флешками не хочется, есть ли команды для установки centOS сразу вместо текущей ос ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть такая опция в установщике. Даже можно примонтировать /home из mint в /home для CentOS

Comment: а волшебная команда типа:apt-get install centOS6_x64 есть ? =)

Comment: не юморите. через apt-get или yum можно обновить ИМЕЮЩУЮСЯ систему. А Вы желаете ДРУГУЮ. Поэтому ЛУЧШЕ всего скачать DVD, ну или CD, а потом по yum обновить и установить все что нужно.

Comment: Насчёт волшебной команды: волшебная команда в вашем случае есть, выглядит как `cd / && rm -rf *` от имени root. После этого вы новую систему поставите настолько быстро, насколько вам она будет нужна, не взирая на диски, флешки и прочие вещи. Только учтите, что вся инфа накроется медным тазом (ну это я на всякий случай, а то потом скажете, мол, насоветовал тут)

Comment: "*вся инфа накроется медным тазом*" - только в том случае, если диск был не разбит как нужно и целиком использовался для **/**. В самом простом случае достаточно выделить отдельный раздел для `/home` и туда же бэкапить что-нибудь нужное из `/etc` c компанией, и потери будут не так ощутимы :)

Comment: Лучше так: `rm -rf /*`

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле есть програмка debootstrap для дебианоидов, делает все сама. Центос и Федору можно поставить также находясь в другом линуксе.
Нужна програмка rpm - ставится из репозитория и yum - ставится через rpm)

Если это добро запустится то нужно отрезать раздел диска и создать там корневую фс для центоса, потом обновить граб и всё должно запускаться после перезагрузки.

https://www.virtualmaster.com/how-to-create-image-from-scratch/ тут из безопасного режима устанавливают систему